# Is it possible to use Logic App or Pipeline to check the Excel data attached to an incoming email?

Tags: azure

Is it possible to use Logic App or Pipeline to check the Excel data attached to an incoming email?

As shown in the image, the Excel data has OK and NG in a fixed place. There are 4 sheets of this Excel data and I want to check all of them.

enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ldml.png)/i.stack.imgur.com/EGaRq.png

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this in a number of ways.

### Office 365

You can use the trigger When an Email is received in outlook. This will poll the mailbox at a time set by you. [See docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-office365-outlook)

[image: logic app screen shot]

[image]

### Non Office 365 Emails

If you need a trigger based on a received email that is not via office 365 then you can use SendGrid to set up a webhook when an email is received. You can then use a logic app to receive this with an HTTP trigger and read the files.

I have a [blog post on reading and parsing inbound emails with sendgrid and azure logic apps](https://www.blueboxes.co.uk/reading-and-parsing-inbound-emails-with-sendgrid-and-azure-logic-apps)

Once you have the file you can use the logic app to read the excel sheet using the Excel actions of the office 365 connector.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using SendGrid?

Comment: thankyou!!!Sorry for the additional questions...
Can Excel data (xlsm) received by e-mail be processed as is? If so, which action would be best?
Excel actions are onedrive or business image,...